# Complicated SQL Server SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the list of workers who work less hours a week than average in each shop.

**Workers:**

- name
- hours (amout of hours a worker works a week)
- shop (a shop a worker works in)

This gives me the list of pairs (shop, average hours in the shop):

```
SELECT shop, AVG(hours) AS 'av' FROM Workers GROUP BY shop
```

This is my 'Pseudo SQL':

```
SELECT 
    name, hours, 
    (SELECT shop, AVG(hours) AS 'av' FROM Workers GROUP BY shop).av 
FROM Workers 
WHERE 
   (SELECT shop, AVG(hours) AS 'av' FROM Workers GROUP BY shop).av > Workers.hours 
   AND (SELECT shop, AVG(hours) AS 'av' FROM Workers GROUP BY shop).shop = Workers.shop
```

I need this to be done in a single T-SQL query. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mind describing you table schemas? Kind of hard to help out with just this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.  I don't understand your query entirely (what's the "Pracownicy" table?), but this should give you an idea (untested query):

```
SELECT w.name,
       w.hours,
       w.shop,
       avg.average
  FROM Workers AS w,
       (SELECT shop,
               AVG(hours) AS average
          FROM Workers
        GROUP BY shop) AS avg
 WHERE w.shop = avg.shop
   AND w.hours < avg.average
```

Note the trick here: using a query as a table in the FROM clause.  This allows you to cut down on the number of repetitive subselects.

Comment: Sorry for 'Pracownicy' I forgot to translate it to 'Workers'. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
With averageHours as (SELECT shop, AVG(hours) AS 'av' FROM Workers GROUP BY shop)
SELECT name, hours, averageHours.av
FROM Workers WHERE averageHours.av > Workers.hours 
             AND averageHours.shop = Workers.shop
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT NAME FROM TABLE T1 WHERE T1.HOUR < ( SELECT AVG(HOUR) FROM TABLE GROUP BY T1.NAME )`

This is most easiest query which would work wihtout any chaos.

Comment: You're not handling the condition where each worker is compared to the average for their own shop.